# CSS Top margin shrinks when window shrinks

Tags: css, margin, window-resize

I want a top margin for my  webpage of say 100px when the window is maximised, but if the user resizes the window to shrink it I want this margin to shrink. The margin should have a minimum size of say 10px and should shrink in proportion to the window height.

An example if what I am trying to emulate is http://www.bing.com/

How would I go about implementing this in CSS? I'm stuggling with `min-height`, `min-width`, `height` and `width` at the moment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing some code, it's difficult to give a great suggestion. But, you can style the html and body to be 100% height which should actually conform to the height of the viewable portion of the browser:

```
html, body{ margin:0; padding:0; height:100%; }
```

From there, you can add a div directly into the body and give that a height that is a percentage:

```
#push{ height: 15%; }
```

Your body html would look something like:

```
<body>
    <div id="push"></div>
    <div>
        asdf asdf
    </div>
</body>
```

When the body height changes, so will the push height. You may need to tweak that number to get it to your liking. You can also give the push a min-height, but that is not supported in IE6. Also, that 100% html / body could give you trouble later depending on how you're doing your footer and things, so beware and good luck.